# Artifact when drawing with a rotation

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I have noticed a weird artifact occuring when I'm drawing a texture in a rotated rectangle.

My basic picture is this :

[image]

When I draw "horizontally", the result is as expected :

[image]

But when I start drawing them in a rotated square, 2 artifacts apear on the bottom and on the right of the circle.

[image]

I can't seam to figure out where they came from...

Any ideas ?

EDIT : Sorry, forgot to add my drawing code :

```
GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, graphics.TextureId);
GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactorDest.OneMinusSrcAlpha);

GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads);

Point tlCorner = displayObject.LocalToGlobal(0,0);
Point trCorner = displayObject.LocalToGlobal(displayObject.Width, 0);
Point brCorner = displayObject.LocalToGlobal(displayObject.Width, displayObject.Height);
Point blCorner = displayObject.LocalToGlobal(0, displayObject.Height);

GL.TexCoord2(0.0f, 0.0f);
GL.Vertex2(tlCorner.X, tlCorner.Y);

GL.TexCoord2(1.0f, 0.0f);
GL.Vertex2(trCorner.X, trCorner.Y);

GL.TexCoord2(1.0f, 1.0f);
GL.Vertex2(brCorner.X, brCorner.Y);

GL.TexCoord2(0.0f, 1.0f);
GL.Vertex2(blCorner.X, blCorner.Y);

GL.End();

GL.Disable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
GL.Disable(EnableCap.Blend);
```

Comment: Check your texture wrapping modes; ensure they are clamped and not repeating.

Comment: Indeed , it was that, I defined 2 TexParameter (TextureWrapS and TextureWrap) to ClampToEdge and it was gone ! If you would mind putting your answer in an aswer post, I would gladly set it as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in comment by Remy Grandin the artifact may be "removed" by setting texture wrapping modes to ClampToEdge. I would disagree upon it being an answer though although solving the immediate problem.

If looking closely on the images there are also artifacts on top and left of the circles. This is because of opengl sampling outside the texture. Wrapping mode decides what happens when sampling outside a texture. As far as I understand this is not exactly what you want, although the effect may seem desirable for the moment.

Imagine sampling texture coordinate 1.1. Default is to "repeat", which is a simple fmod(x, 1.0). In our example giving 0.1. The artifact on the right side of the rectangle is actually a piece of the left part of the rectangle. "ClampToEdge" puts the coordinate from 1.1 to 1.0. This does NOT solve your artifacts on the left side since the left side has issues with the rectangle not covering pixels all the way, in contrast with the right side covering too much. No wrapping mode in the world can fix that.

The solution is to center your circle in the texture data and have a white/invisible border (not sure what you have there), making wrapping mode ultimately insignificant until you want to actually wish to define texture coordinates beyond 0.0-1.0 range. Because that is what wrapping mode does.

You did not include the left and top artifacts in the question but I took the liberty noting them out for you.